# Compute new column in pandas using conditional on other columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe which looks like this

```
pd.DataFrame({'A': [5, 2, -3, -2, 1],
   ...:                    'B': [9, -1, 7, -4, 3],
   ...:                    'C': [-5, 2, -6, -8, 9]})
Out[21]: 
   A  B  C
0  5  9 -5
1  2 -1  2
2 -3  7 -6
3 -2 -4 -8
4  1  3  9
```

For each column value > 0 I want to add 1 and for each column value < 0 I want to subtract 1 before summing up all columns.

resulting dataframe should look like this

```
   A  B  C   D   Logic
0  5  9 -5  10   (5+1)+(9+1)+(-5-1)
1  2 -1  2   4   (2+1)+(-1-1)+(2+1)
2 -3  7 -6  -3
3 -2 -4 -8 -17
4  1  3  9  16
```

what is the easiest/quickest way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```
df['D'] = df.add(np.where(df>0, 1, -1)).sum(axis=1)

print(df)

   A  B  C   D
0  5  9 -5  10
1  2 -1  2   4
2 -3  7 -6  -3
3 -2 -4 -8 -17
4  1  3  9  16
```

---

**Explanation**

Create an array of 1 & -1 which can be added to the dataframe using [`add`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.add.html):

```
>>> np.where(df>0, 1, -1)

array([[ 1,  1, -1],
       [ 1, -1,  1],
       [-1,  1, -1],
       [-1, -1, -1],
       [ 1,  1,  1]])
```

Comment: good, `df.add` is more concise :) +1. I probably will delete my answer. By the way its [not me](https://snipboard.io/Df7HGZ.jpg)

Comment: thank you. what if i dont want to add 1 but do the following  (1+5) + (1+9) + (1-5). logic for my first row. so depending on whether value is >0 or <0 want 1+value or 1-value

Comment: @idt_tt then you simply do `df.add(1).sum(axis=1)`

Comment: @YOLO you are right. my problem is slightly more complex though so for x<0 i need to (1-x)^-1 (to the power of -1) any easy solution here?

Comment: @idt_tt so for row 1 what will be the expected answer, will it be 10+16-7 ?

Comment: @YOLO (1+5)+(1+9)+((1-(-5))^-1) =  16.1667. I posted a new question

Answer (score 0):

Numpy has a method called [`numpy.sign`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.sign.html) which converts positive number to 1 and negative to -1.

```
df['D'] = df.add(np.sign(df)).sum(axis=1)
```